# Can 〜てなんかいない contract to 〜てなんかない?

Tags: contractions

In [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12605/1478), nkjt gives the following example of **なんか** insertion:

```
　　　　待ってないんだから　→　待ってなんかないんだから
```

On the left-hand side, it appears that 〜ていない is contracted to 〜てない.  This is very common, of course, but as I understand it, contractions of いる to る **only happen after 〜て**, as in the following examples:

```
　　　　持っている　　→　持ってる
　　　　持っていない　→　持ってない
　　　　持っています　→　持ってます
```

In the example with **なんか** inserted, it seems that いない is contracted to ない, even though it follows something other than 〜て!

**Is this possible?**

If it is, I'm forced to wonder about the いません version, as well:

```
　　　　持っていない　　→　持ってなんかない
　　　　持っていません　→　持ってなんかません
```

If they *are* acceptable, how do you explain it?  Is my "only after 〜て" rule incorrect?

Comment: As an aside: in reading about Japanese linguistics, I sometimes see words written like `aruk-` (for 歩く) or `mi-` (for 見る).  If the auxiliary いる is written `i-`, then how is the contracted auxiliary written?  Writing it `-` feels silly.

Comment: I don't know if these forms are standard/linguistically acceptable, but basically I think the なんか version may be an emphatic version of ~ては<い>ない.  And while looking to see if I could find any better references than my gut feelings, I found: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/

Comment: I think of なんか as the Japanese equivalent of the English "like" interjection. It is a sure marker for colloquialisms, allowing "swallowing" the い when transcribing the spoken word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～てなんかない is a valid contraction of ～てなんかいない in spoken Japanese. I personally hear ～てなんかません as unnatural, but a Google search suggests that this is also technically valid, though significantly less common. (Incidentally, I find it a bit humorous that the seemingly overwhelming majority of results for "てなんかない" are 「泣いてなんかない」.)

I would say that your intuition that いない can only contract to ない after ～て is very close, and possibly exactly right... but it's likely not the ～て, but rather that it's being used as a kind of helper to another verb, which even after inserting なんか, is still the case. That's just my own guess, though.

Comment: `泣いてなんかない` sounds like something a guy would say if he was accused of crying for being too feminine/emotional/etc.